# how to correctly make a onmouseout event for a UL?

Tags: html, events, html-lists, mouseout

Check this simple code:

```
<ul onmouseout='alert(1)'>
    <li>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</li>
    <li>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</li>
    <li>ccccccccccccccccccccccccc</li>
</ul>
```

The `onmouseout` event is fired even when I am inside the `UL` traversing the `LI` with the mouse.

This is with FireFox, how can I make it right, so the event is fired when I really leave the `UL`?

Comment: If you want to **learn** `JavaScript`, you should consider **not** listening to JQuery/Prototype answers, but rather reading the link @Lourens mentioned.
Some advice : use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to provide your example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the jQUery [mouseout](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/),  or the jQuery [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) functions for this, [The same exists for Mootools](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Event#Element-Events).

**EDIT**

The mouse out event will be triggered whenever you leave one li and go to the next, but mouseleave is triggered only on leaving the whole of the div

```
$('#id').mouseleave(function(){
alert("left the div");  
});
```

Comment: +1 for `mouseleave` - `mouseout` will exhibit the same behaviour that the OP wants to avoid.

Comment: the `mouseleave` event doesnt do that. Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/balanivash/zqna3/1)

Comment: That's what I'm saying (and hence the +1): `mouseleave` good, `mouseout` bad :)

Comment: oh.. sry.. :) dint notice that .. :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to mouseout firing on the li. So youll have to prevent the li.mouseout event from bubling

read up on http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html